git clone always tries to connect to IP 10.255.255.254 (port 2491), but no proxy is configured
I'm trying to run the following command:
$ git clone https://github.com/LazyVim/starter ~/.config/nvim
However, I get this error message:

Cloning into '/home/leonardo/.config/nvim'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/LazyVim/starter/': Failed to connect to 10.255.255.254 port 2491: Connection refused

I haven't set up any proxy related to this IP, and my terminal proxy settings also don't point to 10.255.255.254.
enter image description here
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
What I've tried:
Clearing Git proxy settings:
I ran the following commands to ensure Git isn't using any proxy:
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy

Clearing terminal proxy settings:
I verified that my terminal environment variables (http_proxy, https_proxy, etc.) are not set.
Checking /etc/resolv.conf:
The nameserver entries in this file don't point to 10.255.255.254.
I suspected WSL might automatically regenerate this file, so I restricted modifications to it using:
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf

Reinstalling Git:
I completely removed and reinstalled Git, but the issue persists.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. It's a well-known WSL problem...
